# Storing json structure for edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relationship that only make sense to stored in a json structure with key, value. However, I find neo4j only supports storing json string in nodes. Is there a way to store json string in edges? If not, what is the best practice to support this in my graph?

btw, I can store the json string in my graph, just does not have the neo4j primitive to extract it out. Right now, I have to load it out of neo4j and crack the json to make some decisions.

Comment: I have similar use case so I store the data as json string then to use it in the query by converting the json string into json using an apoc function.

Comment: what is your query? @jose_bacoy